# Finding authors who published in a certain journal

Tags: publications, journals, authorship, scopus, web-of-science

I was told by faculty in my field that top journals A and B sort of have an arch-rivalry in the sense that people either choose to publish in A and not B, or the other way around, due to some huge schism in the past. (Keeping this slightly vague to not perfectly identify my field)

Naturally, I was interested to figure out who has ever bridged the gap between journals A and B and published papers there both. However, it seems like neither **Scopus** nor **Web of Science** offers any functionality that would help in my search - one can search for all documents that an author published, but not authors that have published in a journal (or in my case, multiple journals).

Are there any resources out there that would help me in my search, beyond doing web-crawling on the journal webpages and comparing them manually? I am intrigued to find out this answer, but I don't know if I am willing to commit that much time...

Comment: It is not impossible: You should do a search (on Web of Science or Scopus or LENS or similar databases) for all publications from journal A and journal B, download the results, and use R or Python to parse each author and filter only those authors who have published in both journals. - - But this requires coding skills, and I am not aware of an easier approach just using the browser interfaces of the database without additional data wrangling. - If you can name us the two journals, perhaps someone can do that for you.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in Web of Science and Scopus - just search by "Publication name" and  "Source title" respectively.